# asp.net razor query if else condition

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a query which brings picture from database  based on id which looks like this

```
var selectphotos = "Select * from ItemPhotos where ItemID= @0";
```

I want to hide image div if that query has 0 results or no pictures. 
I tried

```
if(selectphotos.Count()  > 0 ){
<div> with pics </div>
}else{
<p>just msg </p>
}
```

It didn't work pls help

Comment: _"It didn't work"_ is not an error. What do you expect to happen and what does happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectphotos` is a `string` in what you have shown containing the SQL query. You should do the test with `Count() > 0` on the **results** of this query:

```
if (resultsOfYourSQLQuery.Count() > 0) {
    <div> with pics </div>
} else {
    <p>just msg </p>
}
```

If you are using WebMatrix you could execute the query like that:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_NAME");
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM ItemPhotos WHERE ItemID=@0";
    int itemId = 123; // you should probably fetch this from the request or something
    var results = db.Query(sql, itemId);
}

if (results.Count() > 0) {
    <div> with pics </div>
} else {
    <p>just msg </p>
}
```

Comment: could you pls give me rought syntax for that ?

Comment: Rough syntax for what? Executing a SQL query? There are gazillions of ways and syntaxes to execute a SQL query in .NET. Depending on your specific scenario, the data access engine you are using and whether you are using an ORM or not there might be so many different ways.

Comment: Rough syntax for how to do a basic query? Any beginners tutorial should cover that.